# NullException error in MVC first code entity

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have MVC first code project but I get below error
[image: error pic]

First code! So there is no default database.

Model class

```
public class Applicant
{
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Context class:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public List<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Applicant>().Property(r => r.ApplicantID)
                     .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

Applicant repasority class:

```
public  Applicant Create(string username, string password, int phoneNumber, out int existResult)
{
    if (context.Applicants.Where(x => x.UserName == username).ToString() != null)
    {
        applicant = new Applicant()
        {
            UserName = username,
            Password = password,
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
        };
        context.Applicants.Add(applicant);
        existResult = 1;
        return applicant;
    }
    existResult = 0;
    return applicant;   
}
```

And I added below code to my web.config in my web solution:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Data Source=.;Catalog=Homi;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" name="Context" />
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your care! what do you mean exactly?

Comment: is something less?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/861716. Only *you* can debug your code and check what's null (also applies to `ArgumentNullException`). Side note: `context.Applicants.Where(x => x.UserName == username).ToString()` returns the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I find answer.

first I changed context class to this like below

add this part:

```
public Context()
    {
        base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        base.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }
```

and changed string to DbSet:

```
    public DbSet<Applicant> Applicants { get; set; }
```

second

a cool mistake :D I forgot to do this:

> Project –> Manage NuGet Packages…
>
> Note: If you don’t have the Manage NuGet Packages… option you should
>   install the latest version of NuGet
>
> Select the Online tab
>
> Select the EntityFramework package
>
> Click Install

after all for some place of code if above ways doesn't work try{}catch{}
was last solution!

and in end when I run my web nothing saved in my db :(
it was very important to put "context.SaveChanges();" in applicant repository after "context.Add(applicant);"

that's all
tnx